# MonoTouch: Approaching Obsolete iOS methods

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, obsolete

As iOS is upgraded the signatures and methods of older versions get marked as **obsolete** by MonoTouch.

My question is, if we take the suggestion for a new method that MonoTouch offers , will we be negatively affecting older iOS versions?

I understand that new features, such as Facebook in iOS 6 are not available in 4.3, but this question is more about migration for MonoTouch apps to higher versions of IOS while keeping compatibility.

For example:

*An iOS 4.3 device running a MonoTouch 6 app : Will removing obsolete methods and replacing them with the new ones work still ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no single, general, answer as it depend why the method/type was obsoleted.

Most `[Obsolete]` attributes have a message stating why you should avoid them. They mostly fall in two groups:

- There was a binding error in the API, e.g. a typo. A new API was added to correct this (and its name should be part of the description). In this case there is no problem, for a 4.3 device, to use the new API added in MonoTouch 6.x;
- Apple introduced a new API and deprecated the use of an older one. In this case the description should state the new API and the iOS version where it applies. You should **not** use the new API (e.g. anything added in iOS 6.0) if you wish to target older devices (e.g. 5.x).

If you find `[Obsolete]` method/types without any text message or when the text is not clear enough to allow you to make a clear decision please [file a bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) so it can be corrected.

Comment: How do we set MonoTouch to debug to an older installed Simulator?

Comment: So for virtual method overrides, do we implement both? e.g. The new orientation members of UIViewControllers in iOS6 - overriding the old method gives the warning: `warning CS0618: MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(MonoTouch.UIKit.UIInterfaceOrientation) is obsolete: Deprecated in iOS6. Replace it with both GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations and PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`.
So if we are building against the 6.0 SDK, but supporting iOS 5+, do we need to override both the old and new members and ignore the obsolete warnings?

Comment: **my** advice is that, *as long as you support 5.x*, to only use the API available in 5.0. Otherwise you end up with different code running on different version and that's a nightmare to test properly. I know that in some case you can't avoid it - but whenever you can be happy :-)

Answer (score 1):

This may help in testing. Add old iPhone Simulators:

**open xcode and in the top menu go to xcode >> preferences >> Downloads and you will be given the option to download old sdks to use with xcode. You can also download command line tools and Device Debugging Support.**

This will let you go to the simulators  Hardware/Version menu and choose 4.3 or 5.0 or 5.1 etc.

Comment: If you have older Xcode version installed you'll be able (with Xcode 4.5 selected in MD) to download/use the simulators down to iOS 4.3 (w/Xcode 4.2 also installed). Otherwise (with only Xcode 4.5) you won't be able to go down to iOS 4.3.